# Set of all finite intersections of sets in countable subset of powerset is also countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $\mathcal{O}\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ is countably infinite, is the set $$\mathcal{N}:=\left\{\bigcap_{j=1}^n O_j :\; O_j\in \mathcal{O},\; n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$
necessarily countable?

Comment: We could write $\mathcal O=\{O_i\mid i\in\mathbb N\}$ so that an element of $\mathcal N$ corresponds with a finite subset of $\mathbb N$. Does that help you enough?